# How to Import Excel file into mysql Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

this is my HTML code for the upload form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The PHP code for the connection to the database and the import is below.

```
 <?
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Unable To Connect");
mysql_select_db("tutorial") or die("Database Not Found"); 
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";

        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //print_r($emapData);
            //exit();
             $count++;                                  


            $sql = "INSERT into customers values ('','$emapData[1]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')";
            mysql_query($sql);

        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        header('Location: test.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>
```

This is what I tried but after I upload , it imports unreadable alphabets into my database table columns

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Well Excel != csv so what did you expect

Comment: ok ..that is why? well how do I get the excel file then. I thought it to be the same.

Comment: Please stop using any mysql_* functions and switch to their mysqli_* counterparts or PDO as all mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Mixing <? and <?php opening tags is not the best practice either...

Answer (score 0):

use PHPExcel to import excel or CSV in database https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/